# Python: How to find sum of K consecutive elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sum

Link for the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/dinnertimemarch20/challenges/dashboard-queries/problem

Below is my attempt at the problem. It gives a time limit exceeded error when N and Q = 100,000 so what would be a faster way?

```
N,Q = map(int,input().split())
x = 0
m = []
for i in range(0,N+1):
    m.append(0)
#print(m)
for q in range(0,Q):
    n = list(map(int,input().split()))
    if n[0] == 2:
        for i in range(n[1]-1,len(m)):
            m[i] = m[i] + n[2]
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(m)):
            if m[i] >= n[1]:
                print(i+1)
                break
```

Comment: It will be very beneficial for you if you do it yourself. After all, this is what these challenges are for. You can use these two hints: 1) your program has nested loops which are increasing the runtime. Think about a solution which can solve it without nested loops. 2) There is always a time-space trade-off. When you are trying to optimise time, you will need to use more memory (meaning you will have to store results for faster calculations).

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time and still don't get how to do this faster